# trying to update my database using php with a for loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

This is what I did so far but my code is not updating the database, no error showing, nothing, but it's not working. Please help me, I really need it and I'm new to `php`.

Basically what I am trying to do is to show the `id` name and firstname of each one on the database, and the teacher has to put the notes for each one.

```
    <?php
            include('config.php');
        ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>crypto </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>crypto !</h1>
            <h2>Entrez les données demandées :</h2>
            <table>
                <div class="content">
                    <form action="crypto.php" method="post">
                    <div class="center">


            <td class="left"> <?php mysql_query ( ' select id  from       etudient_l2'); ?></td>
            <td class="left"> <?php  mysql_query ( ' select nom  from etudient_l2'); ?> </td>
            <td class="left"> <?php  mysql_query ( ' select prenom  from etudient_l2'); ?> </td>

            <label for="test1">test1</label><input type="text" name="test1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['test1'])); ?>" /><br />
            <label for="test2">test2</label><input type="text" name="test2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['test2'])); ?>" /><br />
            <label for="participation">participation</label><input type="text" name="participation" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['participation'])); ?>" /><br />
            <label for="examen">Examen</label><input type="text" name="examen" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['examen'])); ?>" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
       </table>


      <?php
    if(isset($_POST['test1'], $_POST['test2'], $_POST['participation'],    $_POST['examen']) )
{




    //On récupère les valeurs entrées par l'utilisateur :

     $test1=$_POST['test1'];
    $test2=$_POST['test2'];
    $participation=$_POST['participation'];
    $examen=$_POST['examen'];



    $result=mysql_query('select * from etudient_l2');
    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "$num_rows";
    for($i=1; $i<= $num_rows ; $i++)
    {
    $sql = "UPDATE etudient_l2 SET                  test1_res='$test1',test2_res='$test2',participation_res='$participation',examen_         res='$examen' where id='$i'"; 


        }


        // on ferme la connexion
       mysql_close();
       >


      <?php
      }
       ?>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: this code is messed up. point out where you need help?

Comment: *"no error showing"* - That's because you're not checking for them. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: why the query has been written inside `<td class="left">`

Comment: One obvious error is this `examen_         res` notice the spaces? There are nine in there in `$sql = "UPDATE etudient_l2 SET` which you are not even querying with. It's just a stray statement.

Comment: i was doing this  <?php echo $dnn['id']; ?> but there where too many errors abt undefined variable dnn so i changed it to that but it doesnt even showthe id the name and the firstname

Comment: check your `isset() condition`

Comment: @zoulikha u r only `quering` not fetching the value

Comment: If your teachers are teaching you to use mysql extensions that point out to them that mysql is DEPRECATED and should NOT BE USED. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php  It is no wonder that they have not taught you enough to be able to write code that has a chance of working if they do not know this.

Comment: You had my vote at `plzz`. I just wonder if you'll flunk this or not, you kinda deserve to study this whole thing again util you get it right.

Comment: You have to go through the "good" tutorials. This code is and am sorry to say, unsalvageable. We don't fix "homework".

Comment: my teachers didnt teach us php i did all the research by my self its kind of the end of the year thing ok a question how to fetch the values ??!

Comment: ok guys can u atleast help me with the right boucle to update the whole table pllz and i will do  the rst by self

Comment: i think first indent the code properly , it looks shaggy maybe the error is solved

Comment: i added mysql_query($sql); but its adding the same numbers the the whole table ??!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just correcting your code first change your HTML like below

```
<label for="test1">test1</label>
<input type="text" name="test1" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['test1'])){echo $_POST['test1'];} ?>" />
<br />
<label for="test2">test2</label>
<input type="text" name="test2" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['test2'])){ echo $_POST['test2'];} ?>" />
<br />
<label for="participation">participation</label>
<input type="text" name="participation" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['participation'])){ echo $_POST['participation'];} ?>" />
<br />
<label for="examen">Examen</label>
<input type="text" name="examen" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['examen'])){ echo $_POST['examen'];} ?>" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="submit" />
```

than change some php code like below

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$test1=$_POST['test1'];
$test2=$_POST['test2'];
$participation=$_POST['participation'];
$examen=$_POST['examen'];

$result=mysql_query("select * from etudient_l2");
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
for($i=1; $i<=$num_rows;$i++)
{
$sql =mysql_query("UPDATE `etudient_l2` SET `test1_res`='".$test1."',`test2_res`='".$test2."',`participation_res`='".$participation."',`examen_res`='".$examen."' where `id`='".$i."'"); 
}


    // on ferme la connexion
   mysql_close();

  }
   ?>
```

Rest is in your hand i don't take the guarantee based on your code again i am just correcting you.

---

To help you during testing:

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

- Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: `'".$participation'` is missing a `."` => `'".$participation."'`

Comment: No worries Vicky. Syntax highlighting was showing something being unfinished somewhere. That's when I found that one.

Comment: @vicky i added mysql_query and its updating the table but in a one submit its apdating the whole table with the same values ??!!!!!!  someone help me pllz

Comment: @Fred-ii- can u help me plz the code is aupating the whole table with the same values at the first tie even im using id ??!

Comment: @zoulikha u r using id that is ok but u r updating using for loop with the same value again and again that's why its updating with the same value

Comment: !!!! so its not the correct way??§!  and how im suppose to change the whole table??

Comment: @zoulikha you guessed it right its not the correct way.First learn than try if not worked than google it if not find than u have to post here any thing

Comment: @Vicky im googling the whole weekened and i  said it before it must be ready this monday. plz just give me an idea how to pull it throw

Comment: @zoulikha what do u actually want to do plz describe it briefly with your database structure and ur need!!

Comment: @Vicky well its a website for teachers to be able to update the notes so my database it has 3tables adminstration teachers and student so when the teacher conncet he will be able to change the notes the table of student conten (id name prenom test1_res test2_res participation_res examen_res ) and he will keep on changing the note student by a student and click one submit to change them all i hope u understood me

Comment: @zoulikha well it looks like a module that u r working on!! anyway what is `note` who will insert it and what's the relation between `note` and the `student`

Comment: sorry @Vicky im mixing english with frensh note is the mark that the teacher (user) gonna give to the student and when i say mark i mean "test1_res, test2_res,participation_res,examen_res

Comment: @zoulikha i think u should make a separate table for marks where the marks will insert with the student id and an auto increment id and you can show all the marks using select query with while loop and inside while loop you can give anchor tag with the auto increment id in query string get that string fetch all the value by that id update marks and fire an update query with updated marks where id=auto incremented id which u got from query string

Comment: @zoulikha hope u understood!! i gotta go!! happy weekend :)

Comment: @Vicky not quite well but thank u for ur help anyway ^_^